# mysql select with union all

Tags: mysql, union-all

I got

TableA

```
| id | san | status |       created       |
-------------------------------------------
| 1  | 100 |   3    | 2013-11-01 19:26:20 |
| 2  | 200 |   8    | 2013-11-02 03:19:35 |
| 3  | 300 |   1    | 2013-11-03 06:13:38 |
| 4  | 100 |   2    | 2013-11-06 08:28:37 |
| 5  | 100 |   4    | 2013-11-27 19:00:00 |
| 6  | 200 |   1    | 2013-11-27 19:16:22 |
| 7  | 200 |   3    | 2013-11-27 19:33:33 |
| 8  | 300 |   5    | 2013-11-27 19:50:29 |
```

TableB

```
| san | san-name |
------------------
| 100 |   xxx1   |
| 200 |   xxx2   |
| 300 |   xxx3   |
```

with this query (**using union all because i have tons of rows**)

```
SELECT id, max(lastdate) AS lastdate, max(san) AS san
FROM
    (SELECT `san` AS id,
            `created` AS lastdate,
            '' AS san
     FROM `TableA` a
     UNION ALL
     SELECT `san` AS id,
            cast(null as datetime) AS lastdate,
            `san-name` AS san
     FROM `TableB` b
    ) sq
GROUP BY id 
ORDER BY san ASC
```

i get this result (everything works perfect)

```
| id  |      lastdate       |   san   |
--------------------------------------
| 100 | 2013-11-27 19:00:00 |   xxx1  |
| 200 | 2013-11-27 19:33:33 |   xxx2  |
| 300 | 2013-11-27 19:50:29 |   xxx3  |
```

**but now i want to add also the "status" of the latest "created" "id" into my result.**

from TableA i want the rows ( see <- LATEST SAN ..... )

```
| id | san | status |       created       |
-------------------------------------------
| 1  | 100 |   3    | 2013-11-01 19:26:20 |
| 2  | 200 |   8    | 2013-11-02 03:19:35 |
| 3  | 300 |   1    | 2013-11-03 06:13:38 |
| 4  | 100 |   2    | 2013-11-06 08:28:37 |
| 5  | 100 |   4    | 2013-11-27 19:00:00 | <- LATEST SAN 100
| 6  | 200 |   1    | 2013-11-27 19:16:22 |
| 7  | 200 |   3    | 2013-11-27 19:33:33 | <- LATEST SAN 200
| 8  | 300 |   5    | 2013-11-27 19:50:29 | <- LATEST SAN 300
```

and it should look like this:

```
| id  | status |      lastdate       |   san   |
------------------------------------------------
| 100 |    4   | 2013-11-27 19:00:00 |   xxx1  |
| 200 |    3   | 2013-11-27 19:33:33 |   xxx2  |
| 300 |    5   | 2013-11-27 19:50:29 |   xxx3  |
```

i tried it with this code

```
SELECT id, status, max(lastdate) AS lastdate, max(san) AS san
FROM
    (SELECT `san` AS id,
            `created` AS lastdate,
            '' AS san,
            status AS status
     FROM `TableA` a
     UNION ALL
     SELECT `san` AS id,
            cast(null as datetime) AS lastdate,
            `san-name` AS san,
            '' AS status
     FROM `TableB` b
    ) sq
GROUP BY id 
ORDER BY san ASC
```

but it gives me this (WRONG RESULT)

```
| id  | status |      lastdate       |   san   |
------------------------------------------------
| 100 |    3   | 2013-11-27 19:00:00 |   xxx1  |
| 200 |    8   | 2013-11-27 19:33:33 |   xxx2  |
| 300 |    1   | 2013-11-27 19:50:29 |   xxx3  |
```

and not the right one like this

```
| id  | status |      lastdate       |   san   |
------------------------------------------------
| 100 |    4   | 2013-11-27 19:00:00 |   xxx1  |
| 200 |    3   | 2013-11-27 19:33:33 |   xxx2  |
| 300 |    5   | 2013-11-27 19:50:29 |   xxx3  |
```

could somebody help me? :o)

i created a **[sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/bf402b/1)**

best regards

bernte

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would try with this query:

```
SELECT tA.san AS id, tA.status, tA.created AS lastdate, tB.`san-name`
FROM
  tableA tA INNER JOIN (SELECT san, MAX(created) AS max_created
                        FROM tableA
                        GROUP BY san) m
  ON tA.san=m.san AND tA.created=m.max_created
  INNER JOIN tableB tB
  ON tA.san=tB.san
```

Please see fiddle [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/512e18/6).

**Edit**

If you need to return all records from tableB, and only the records that match you need to use a RIGHT JOIN (which is a little uncommon) or we can swap the order of the tables joined and use a LEFT JOIN, like this:

```
SELECT tB.san AS id, tA.status, tA.created AS lastdate, tB.`san-name`
FROM
  tableB tB LEFT JOIN
  (SELECT san, MAX(created) AS max_created
   FROM tableA
   GROUP BY san) m
  ON tB.san=m.san
  LEFT JOIN TableA tA
  ON tA.san=m.san AND tA.created=m.max_created
```

Fiddle is [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/97dbc/8).

Comment: hi.. thanks for your comment! i will try this later on my server. hope your code is fast :D with my old code it took 30seconds.. so i had to choose union all

Comment: @bernte I hope it is correct and as fast as a UNION query :) if it is it should also be easier to read! If it is too slow, I would try to add an index on san column on both tables, and also on created column.

Comment: how should the index look like? i have never done this before

Comment: @bernte i would try with a combined index `CREATE INDEX idx1 ON tableA (san, created);` and with `CREATE UNIQUE INDEX idx2 ON tableB (san);`

Comment: i forget to add in TableB san 400 so that i get this result http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/97dbc/4 (with old script). i need an empty date for the lastdate and the right status. is that also possible?

Comment: @bernte then you need a RIGHT JOIN or a LEFT JOIN... please see my updated answer!

Comment: marked as accepted answer! :D THANK YOU! is the INDEX from above the same for the new version?

Comment: @bernte thank you! :D yes index should be the same... maybe instead of a single idx1 you could try with two separated indexes `CREATE INDEX idxA1 ON tableA (san);` and `CREATE INDEX idxA2 ON tableA (created);` but it's hard to tell which one is faster than the other... can't be sure but the index you already have should be better!

Comment: ok :D will try this tomorow on my server :D i got many rows.. so i will the which is the best choise. THANK YOU very much! btw.. cool song @ youtube :D